# Find convergence of improper integral.

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

Hello I have to find the convergence of this improper integral: 
$$\int_{e}^{\infty} \frac{1}{x\log^2x} dx$$
So I started by doing the following:
$\lim \limits_{x \to A} \int_{e}^{A} \frac{1}{x\log^2x} dx$, but I don't really know how to solve this integral:$\int_{e}^{A} \frac{1}{x\log^2x} dx$.

Any tips would be great, thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint:** Make the substitution $u=\log x$. Then $du=\frac{1}{x}\,dx$.

Comment: I see, thank you,my integral would become $\int_{e}^{A} \frac{1}{u^2} du$.I am correct?

Comment: Not quite. We need change the bounds, to $1$ and $\log A$.

Comment: When you integrate, you will get $1-\frac{1}{\log A}$. Then find the limit of this as $A\to\infty$.

Answer (score 3):

Integration by parts gives us:
$$
\int_e^\infty \frac{dx}{x\ln ^2x} = \left[ \frac{1}{\ln x} \right]_e^\infty +2\int_e^\infty \frac{\ln x \,dx}{x \ln^3 x} = -1 +2\int_e^\infty \frac{dx}{x\ln^2 x}
$$
Thus:
$$
\int_e^\infty \frac{dx}{x\ln^2 x} = 1
$$

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\down}{\downarrow}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}
 \newcommand{\wt}[1]{\widetilde{#1}}$
$\ds{\large\tt\mbox{With}\quad 0\ <\ \delta\ <\ 1\quad\mbox{and}\quad
     \pars{~x\ \equiv\ \expo{-t}\quad\imp\quad t\ =\ -\ln\pars{x}~}:}$

> \begin{align}
> &\color{#66f}{\large\lim_{\delta \to 0^{+}}\bracks{%
> \int_{\epsilon}^{1 - \delta}{\dd x \over x\ln^{2}\pars{x}}
> +\int_{1 + \delta}^{\infty}{\dd x \over x\ln^{2}\pars{x}}}}
> \\[3mm]&=\lim_{\delta \to 0^{+}}\bracks{%
> -\int_{-\ln\pars{\epsilon}}^{-\ln\pars{1 - \delta}}{\dd t \over t^{2}}
> -\int_{-\ln\pars{1 + \delta}}^{-\infty}{\dd t \over t^{2}}}
> \\[3mm]&=\lim_{\delta \to 0^{+}}\bracks{%
> -\,{1 \over \ln\pars{1 - \delta}} +{1 \over \ln\pars{\epsilon}}
> +{1 \over \ln\pars{1 + \delta}}} = \color{#66f}{\large +\infty}
> \end{align}